# Parse String Array to FIle

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

Alright gents I am trying to make a program that reads information from a file and then writes information out to another file.

I am reading from 2 columns first column is an integer (Team#) second column is a string(name of member)

```
1 Sam
3 Bob
6 Jill
3 Mike
1 Terra
1 Juice
6 Tom
6 Lucy
3 Dude
```

And then I have to take the 3rd instance in and output the name of the individual so it will look like this

```
Team    Member
1       Juice
3       Dude
6       Lucy
```

I am having issues with trying to read the text into the array in order to output it, I am trying to use Parse String

My Code

```
package team;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Team {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


    //Output Please wait
    System.out.println("Team Leader Started. Please wait....");


    //Add Read and Write File locations
    File inFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Christ\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Team\\src\\team\\read.txt");
    File outFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Christ\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Team\\src\\team\\outputfile.txt");

    // Initialise Arrays
    int[] team = new int[99];

    String[] name = new String[99];


    // Scanner
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(inFile);
    sc.nextLine();  // move to second line assuming file is not empty.

    // While Loop
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String s = sc.nextLine().trim();
        String[] splitStr = s.split(" ");
        team[Integer.parseInt(splitStr[0])-1] += Integer.parseInt(splitStr[1]);
        name[String.parseString(splitStr[0])-1]++;
    }


    PrintWriter outFileWriter = new PrintWriter(outFile);

    outFileWriter.println("Team Name");



   // For loop 
    for(int i=0;i<99;i++) {

    // Team    
    int t=i+1;

    // Member
    String m = name[i];

    // Output to File
    outFileWriter.println(t + " "+" "+ " " + m);
    }
    outFileWriter.close();


//Output Completed file, reference output file for sucees
System.out.println("Team Leader Completed Successfully");

}
}
```

Can someone please tell me where im going wrong? I do not want the final result only the ability at the moment to output the Team number and then the Member name to my output file.

Please Help ^_^

Comment: where did you learn String.parseString()?

Comment: And what EXACTLY is your problem? What output are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [`Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to store your team members with their corresponding teams.

It allows you to store key/value pairs and to maintain a dynamic list of members for each team.

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    System.out.println("Team Leader Started. Please wait....");

    Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();

    //Add Read and Write File locations
    File inFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Christ\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Team\\src\\team\\read.txt");
    File outFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Christ\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Team\\src\\team\\outputfile.txt");

    // Scanner
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(inFile);

    // While Loop
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        String[] splitStr = s.split(" ");
        Integer id = Integer.parseInt(splitStr[0]);
        String name = splitStr[1];
        List<String> list = map.get(id);
        if(list == null)
            map.put(id, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(name)));
        else {
            list.add(name);
        }
    }
    PrintWriter outFileWriter = new PrintWriter(outFile);
    outFileWriter.println("Team Name");
    // For loop 
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> entry : map.entrySet()){
        outFileWriter.write(entry.getKey()+"\t"+entry.getValue().toString()+"\n");
    }       
    outFileWriter.close();
    //Output Completed file, reference output file for sucees
    System.out.println("Team Leader Completed Successfully");

}
```

Output :

```
Team Name
1   [Sam, Terra, Juice]
3   [Bob, Mike, Dude]
6   [Jill, Tom, Lucy]
```

Comment: That is badass, and a far easier way to set this up, now my only issue is figuring out how to output the third member on each team. Thanks for the help m8

Comment: @Saint For each list stored with the associated team id, you can get the last member with `list.get(list.size()-1);`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of inputted people, then adding a row to the input file denoting the length would allow for array sizes to be the minimum required also this gets rid of 100+ people casing an issue

like:
 #9
1 Sam
3 Bob
6 Jill
3 Mike
1 Terra
1 Juice
6 Tom
6 Lucy
3 Dude